# sending structs over C sockets

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am writing a client server application using TCP sockets on C.
For writing data to the server I am sending a structure like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
   uint64_t IEEE_ADDR;
   uint8_t endpoint;
   char requestedAction;
   uint8_t level;
   uint8_t wc;
   uint8_t address_mode;
   uint8_t gID;
   uint8_t sID;
   uint8_t val1;
   uint8_t val0;
   uint8_t status;
}dsfeedbackPkt;
```

For serialising and sending data I have written following function:

```
void fb_serialise_send(dsfeedbackPkt *pkt)
{
unsigned char buffer[SIZE];
int bytes;

buffer[0] = ((pkt->IEEE_ADDR) >> 56);
buffer[1] = (pkt->IEEE_ADDR) >> 48;
buffer[2] = (pkt->IEEE_ADDR) >> 40;
buffer[3] = (pkt->IEEE_ADDR) >> 32;
buffer[4] = (pkt->IEEE_ADDR) >> 24;
buffer[5] = (pkt->IEEE_ADDR) >> 16;
buffer[6] = (pkt->IEEE_ADDR) >> 8;
buffer[7] = (pkt->IEEE_ADDR);
buffer[8] = (pkt->endpoint);
buffer[9] = pkt -> requestedAction;
buffer[10] = pkt->level;
buffer[11] = pkt-> wc;
buffer[12] = pkt->address_mode;
buffer[13] = pkt-> gID;
buffer[14] = pkt->sID;
buffer[15] = pkt->val1;
buffer[16] = pkt->val0;
buffer[17] = pkt->status;

bytes = write(cli_sockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));

}
```

The problem is the data is being received at the server twice, as in two different packets. The second packet mostly contains garbage.

I have browsed through the internet, there are mostly issues related to endianess. But that is not a problem here, also both client and server know the message length beforehand, only the data is received at the server side twice.

Please can anyone suggest what I have missed?

I made following changes:

```
#define SIZE 18
```

on client side and

```
#define RSIZE 18
```

on server side

and its working 
the problem was using sizeof(dsfeedbackPkt) for defining the size.

Comment: Is the size of the first received packet less than `SIZE`?

Comment: Show us the actual code, where you send and receive data.

Comment: Bug in your unposted receiving code. TCP doesn't deliver data twice.

Comment: The size of first received packet is equal to SIZE

Comment: I am defining  `SIZE` which is equal to the sizeof(dsfeedbackPkt)

Comment: You need to help us help you, there is not enough information here to answer your question.

Comment: You should **always** use a packed structure when reading to it or sending its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am defining SIZE which is equal to the sizeof(dsfeedbackPkt)

Right here is your problem. Due to struct padding, the struct is probably 20 bytes, not 18.

Change `SIZE` to 18 and it should work.

Comment: I changed that to `#define SIZE 18` but, I am still receiving the same error

Comment: The remaining problem is not in the code you have posted so far. Could you pleases add the send/receive code to your question? Also, do you `write` to the socket anywhere else in the code?

Comment: Thanks! I was saving the size of received packet at the server side using sizeof, I made the same change at the server side too and now its working fine...

Comment: I looked up struct padding and now I get it, and I beleive that was the problem.. Thanks!